# Calculate $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{[x]}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f = \dfrac{1}{[x]}$ where $[x]$ denotes greatest integer function.

(a) $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{[x]} = -1$

(b) $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{[x]}$ does Not Exist

(c) Domain of the function is $\mathbb{R}$

(d) Domain Is $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$

Okay so, Domain will be set of points where $[x] \ne 0$

or, $x \ne [0,1)$

So,Domain is given by $\mathbb{R}-[0,1)$

Now, To solve for limit Only Left Hand Limit will exist as $(x \to 0+)$ does Not belong to the domain so I think only one sided limit will exist.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ = $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0-} f(x) = -1$

So, only option (a) seems to be correct according to me .

Is my answer and solution correct? Can someone please check ?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks correct :)

Comment: There must be some typos, I'd think.

Comment: if the limit from the right doesn't exist, then the overall limit doesn't exist, so it is b

Comment: @fGDu94: So (a) is an incorrect choice ?

Comment: yes, but the left limit is indeed -1

Comment: @WlodAA : What kind of typos? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Ok, if not typos then it's just like the author of the problem has no ear for mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x=0$ is an accumulation point for the domain $D$, the right definition of limit at $x=0$ is this: 
$$
\forall \varepsilon  > 0\,\,\,\exists \delta  = \delta \left( \varepsilon  \right) > 0:\forall x \in \left( { - \delta ,\delta } \right) \cap D\setminus\left\{ 0 \right\} \Rightarrow \left| {f\left( x \right) - l} \right| < \varepsilon 
$$
Now
$$
\left( { - \delta ,\delta } \right) \cap D = \left( { - \delta ,0} \right)
$$
and you have that
$$
\forall \varepsilon  > 0\,\,\,\exists \delta  = \delta \left( \varepsilon  \right) > 0:\forall x \in \left( { - \delta ,0} \right) \Rightarrow \left| {f\left( x \right) + 1} \right| < \varepsilon 
$$
and this means that 
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) =  - 1
$$
This is to think as a full limit even though it could seems a left limit. In fact it is not so due to the definition of limit and in particular due to the condition
$$
\forall x \in \left( { - \delta ,\delta } \right) \cap D\setminus\left\{ 0 \right\}
$$

Comment: Thank you,for writing such a detailed answer.

Comment: It is my job: I'm a Mathematical Analysis Professor. You are welcome